# Don't understand behavior of nested transactions in Spring

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

My database has triggers. They trigger after a creation of an entity. I want to test a condition, which depends on results of the trigger execution. So, I need to be able to see those results inside my test. But triggers will trigger after a commit, when the transaction will actually be rolled back.

It seems, that I need to create a new transaction using `transactionTemplate` and `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`. I tried this way, and I able to see results of a trigger execution (horray!). But this way creates another problem: look at the code, I tried to explain a strange behavior via comments.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
public class ServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

    <...>

    @Before
    public final void setUp() {
        clearDatabase();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testFilter() {
        // Note: here database is empty - was cleared by setUp() method
        TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
        tt.setPropagationBehavior(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        tt.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus s) {
                createAndSaveEntity();
            }
        });
        // Here I can see created entity and results of the trigger execution
        // But also I see all entities, which was in the database before setUp()
        // That is very strange! Why they appear if I deleted them?
        <...>
    }
}
```

PS: I use Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE and Neo4j 2.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j does not support nested transactions. Therefore, if a transaction event handler (which I assume you're (correctly) referring to as "trigger") enriches a transaction, it needs to do so in `beforeCommit()` and it will participate in the all-or-nothing operation. Your best bet for testing is let the transaction commit, assert what you need to assert, and clear the database before or after every test.

([GraphAware RestTest](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest) may help with the assertions and clearing, if you really are running against a remote database. If you're using embedded mode for testing, go for [GraphUnit](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/tests#graphunit).)

Your problem is actually something different though. It looks like something (like the SDN `Session`) is not getting cleared between test runs. Either clear it explicitly, or annotate your test with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`.